# Filling Blank/Null values with other values within a column

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010

Ive got a column that is set up like so:

```
-----Col_2-----
     Value 1



     Value 2



 -----------------
```

As you can see there are 2 values within the column, but there are also many spaces as well. What I would like to do is run an `Update` query that would replace the blanks with the 2 values. What I would like is to update the column to look like this:

```
 -------Col_2---------
       Value 1
       Value 1
       Value 1
       Value 2
       Value 2
       value 2
 ---------------------
```

Basically I want to run a query that looks at the first not null value and replaces the following null values with that non null value until it hits the next non null value. Once it hits the next non null value, it then proceeds to replace the following nulls with the new value. Currently, I've got this set up.

```
Update Table1,
 (Select TOP 1 Col_1 AS Z FROM Table1 Where Col_1 Is Not Null)
  Set Col_1 = Z
 Where Col_1 Is Null;
```

This replaces every null value with whatever the first non null value is, but doesn't stop once it hits the next non null value. This results in me getting something like this:

```
---------Col_2-----------
       Value 1
       Value 1
       Value 1
       Value 2
       Value 1
       Value 1
-------------------------
```

Is there a way to add some sort of "do this until" this statement into access? I know you can run if, then statements in PHP and other languages, but not sure how to do this in access or straight SQL.

UPDATE:

There is a second column that contains account numbers, which correlate to the values in `COL_1`. The original set up looks like this.

```
-----Col_1-------Col_2------
    12345         Value 1
    12345         
    12345
    54321         Value 2
    54321         
    54321         
------------------------------
```

Is there a way to use Col_1 in order to get Col_2 to look like:

```
    --------Col_2---------
           Value 1
           Value 1
           Value 1
           Value 2
           Value 2
           Value 2
      ----------------------
```

without having to manually enter Col_1's numbers into the query? By this I mean, I don't want to have to manually enter "12345" or "54321" in the query, but rather have things happen automatically.

Comment: You need a field to `order by` to find the previous non-null value.  Without, how can you know which to update to `Value 1` and which to update to `Value 2`?

Comment: Well that's why I was trying to find a way to update until it hits the next non null value. Some sort of modified SQL if then statement, that will update until the next non null, and then either stop so I can create another query or read that non null and fill the rest of the column.

Comment: What @sgeddes probably intented to say: You first need a way of telling the computer, by which criterion you end up with the column, the way you present it. Probably/Hopefully this is based on one or more other column(s). In the simple case, all of these other values are identical for all rows, for which the Col1 should hold the same value. Should still be doable (in SQL, that is) if the criterion values are in ranges, which do not overlap. If there is actually nothing to sort them on, a declarative solution is unlikely.

Comment: @Abecee there is another column that I originally wanted to use as a criteria, but I was unable to make it work. The second column is a list of Account numbers that match with those values. I will update the original post to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 -- will the same values for `col1` always have the same values for `col2`?  if so, easy to write an `update` statement for that... if multiple values exist, you're back to the same problem since you don't have a column to define which value to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use an update statement, joining the table back to itself.  I think this is the correct syntax in Access:

```
update Table1 
inner join Table1 t2 on Table1.col1 = t2.col1 and t2.col2 is not null
set Table1.col2 = t2.col2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b481e5/1)

Comment: I'm getting a `join expression not supported error` on `t2.col2`

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
UPDATE SomeData SDOuter
SET Col_2 = (SELECT MAX(SDInner.Col_2) FROM SomeData SDInner WHERE SDInner.Col_1 = SDOuter.Col_1 AND Col_2 IS NOT NULL)
WHERE Col_2 IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2eb51/4/2)

Comment: Where are you getting the SDOuter?

Comment: hmmm ended up with a syntax error. in the `(SELECT MAX(SDInner.Col_2) FROM SomeData SDInner WHERE SDInner.Col_1 = SDOuter.Col_1 AND Col_2 IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Any more detail? The Fiddle is playing for me. Not for you? In case, you want to check just this query, you need to remove the reference to the outer statement like this: `SELECT MAX(SDInner.Col_2) FROM SomeData SDInner WHERE  Col_2 IS NOT NULL;` BTW: The `MAX`is in there just in case, for some records Col_2 is specified more than once - but the inner query must not return more than a single row in order not to fail the overall statement.

Comment: … So the inner query's essence/rationale is `SELECT SDInner.Col_2 FROM SomeData SDInner WHERE  Col_2 IS NOT NULL;`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I don't have more more detail other than the fact that it was a `syntax error`. The Fiddle worked last night, my issue was when trying to actually run it on my database, thats when I was receiving the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66622/discussion-between-abecee-and-jcmoney1010).

Comment: Does this need further attention?